# Vue JS - How to bind a value for a button then on click save the value to local storage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage

I have three buttons, I want to make it so that I can select one of these buttons, and then when I click on the button called **Save to local storage**, the value of the selected button is saved in local storage, I use the object that stores the button text and value like

```
{ btnText: "Green", value: "green-value" }
```

Here is my complete code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div v-for="(i, index) in buttonsGroup" :key="index">
        <button
          :class="{
            EthnicityActive:
              i === EthnicityActive && 'EthnicityActive-' + index,
          }"
          v-on:click="EthnicityActive = i"
        >
          {{ i.btnText }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="save">
      <button @click="save">Save to local storage</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      buttonsGroup: [
        { btnText: "Green", value: "green-value" },
        { btnText: "Blue", value: "blue-value" },
        { btnText: "Orange", value: "orange-value" },
      ],
      Save: null,
      EthnicityActive: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    save() {},
  },
};
</script>
```

I think everything is clear here, I created an object, then I used v-for, I got buttons, there is also a Save To Local Storage button, in order to save it to local storage after I selected one of these three buttons

You can also see the given [code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-sea-lpvoo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it's time to complete your method **save**,
like the following lines:

```
save() {
  window.localStorage.setItem('keyName', this.EthnicityActive.value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

okay so far your code is great, just add this in your save methode:

```
save() {
  localStorage.setItem('selectedBtn',JSON.stringify(this.EthnicityActive))
  
},
```

it takes the value of EthnicityActive (the selected btn) and store the object to the localstorage.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for storing your selected button value to local storage
These are the 2 changes

1. set your EthnicityActive to an object. `EthnicityActive: {}`
   Since you are sending an object of button so it should be initialise the `EthnicityActive` to an `empty object i.e {}` rather than `string i.e ''`
2. On click of save you can store `localStorage.setItem(this.EthnicityActive.value)`

Here is the changed code

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      buttonsGroup: [
        { btnText: "Green", value: "green-value" },
        { btnText: "Blue", value: "blue-value" },
        { btnText: "Orange", value: "orange-value" },
      ],
      Save: null,
      EthnicityActive: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    save() {
      localStorage.setItem(this.EthnicityActive.value)
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

update your `save()`method add a `restore()` method, then call `restore()`
on created hook to restore you saved data.

```js
methods: {
    save() {
      localStorage.setItem(
        "EthnicityActive",
        JSON.stringify(this.EthnicityActive)
      );
    },
    restore() {
      this.EthnicityActive = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem("EthnicityActive")
      );
    },
  },
created() {
    this.restore();
  },
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-frost-osdql?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: Dear @MissJulie your code is throwing an error

`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"`

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`